# Time Complexity nested loops

Tags: complexity-theory, nested-loops

The problem:

Find the complexity (big theta) of this function:

```
s <-- 0; 
i = 2;
while (i <= n^2) do 
    for j <-- i to 2i[ln(i)] do
        s <-- s + i - j;
    end
    i <-- i + 2;
end
return (s);
```

I got big theta (n^2(ln(n)) since the for loop will run 2i[ln(i)] - i times which would be ci[ln(i)] time.  And then I multiplied it by n^2 since that is the approximate time of the while loop.

I solved it a different way and got big theta (n^4).

I'm not sure if if my either of my answers are correct, and that is based on my confusion on how to solve these problems when loops are dependent vs independent.

Answer (score 0):

The most robust solution is to sum `2*(2i)*ln(i) - 2i + 1` for `2 <= i <= n^2/2`. We have:

```
1 + 2 + ... + floor(n^2/2) = O(n^4)
```

Whereas:

```
1*ln(1) + ... + floor(n^2/2)*ln(floor(n^2/2)) = O(n^4*ln(n))
```

(The constant `4` doesn't have to be taken into account.)

In fact, you can even get an expression asymptotically equivalent to your sum using a [comparison with an integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence).

Therefore the time complexity is a `O(n^4*ln(n))-O(n^4)+O(n) = O(n^4*ln(n))`.

Without MathJax writing maths is a pain, [here is a more detailed proof](http://mathb.in/80894).

Comment: Can you clarify what you're saying.  I'm confused by how your second sum (1*ln(1) + ... + floor(n^2/2)*ln(floor(n^2/2)) = O(n^4*ln(n))) works.

Comment: @VK20921: It's not obvious. See the "detailed proof". ;)